# How Extract data from html with xpath

Tags: excel, xpath, google-sheets, google-shopping

I'm trying to **extract product price**s from **Google Shopping** with Google Spreadsheet:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com.br/?source=pshome-c-0-3&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfguD5xaHKAhXMiZAKHWjuBi8Q7j8IEA#tbm=shop&q=Samsung+Galaxy+S6&spd=0";"/div[@class='product-results']/div[@class='psli'][2]/div[@class='pslicont']/div[@class='pslmain']/div[@class='pslline'][1]/div[@class='_tyb shop__secondary']/span[@class='price']/b")
```

My **xpath query** is:

```
/div[@class='product-results']/div[@class='psli'][2]/div[@class='pslicont']/div[@class='pslmain']/div[@class='pslline'][1]/div[@class='_tyb shop__secondary']/span[@class='price']/b
```

But i don't have results.

What's Wrong?

HTML from Google Shopping
[image: Google Shopping]

Comment: You can only import the _source_ HTML of this page, which is pretty much only Javascript. The element you are looking for `span[@class = 'price']` is generated by this JS, but not present in the source. To my knowledge, there is no way to get at this content in Google Sheets itself, except custom add-ons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because google in not returning HTML in actual. See the source code of the page

- `view-source:https://www.google.com.br/?source=pshome-c-0-3&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfguD5xaHKAhXMiZAKHWjuBi8Q7j8IEA#tbm=shop&q=Samsung+Galaxy+S6&spd=0`

Comment: Thank you for response. Google uses different scripts for your domains, in Google.FR and GOOGLE.com my code works.

Answer (score 1):

Try using User Agent while getting the HTML from Google. This was a problem I faced a few days ago and got around by mimicking the user agent to be Chrome Browser.
You can find the different ways to mimic User-Agent on Google itself(no pun intended).